# Twitter API : Blocked to retrieve users information in PHP?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to retrieve Twitter users information but I don't why I am blocked whereas it is working for followers information :

```
// Retrieve followers list with array :
$follows = $oTwitter->get("followers/ids.json?screen_name=fifa&cursor=".$cursor);
$foll_array = (array)$follows;
foreach ($foll_array['ids'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val; 
}

// Whereas it is nok for list of attributes (meaning not array) :
$oUser = $oTwitter->get("users/show.json?user_id=4366881");
var_dump(get_object_vars($oUser);

=> I get the following error :
```

array(1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["code"]=> int(50) ["message"]=> string(15) "User not found." } } }

Any idea what is wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this using twurl, that user_id returns just fine.

Comment: Is it linked to my PHP call ?

Comment: I have found the solution. The Twitter API documentation is wrong. 2 parameters are mandatory in really instead of one : user_id and screen_name.

Comment: Using a direct API call (outside of PHP), I am able to call `followers/ids` and `users/show` with only one of those parameters, so I believe the API documentation is correct. Where do you believe this is mandatory?